# Is it possible to encode two 7 bit numbers into one 3-digit number?

Tags: math, binary, bit

Say my first value was 127 and my second value was 32, is it possible to encode both these numbers in a single 3-digit number?

Values I want to encode range from 0-127

Comment: No. 3 digits is slightly less than 10 bits. 10 bits is less than 14 bits.

Comment: Unless you got some info about the numbers (like they are only power of 2....) then only if your digits are in `base = 128` so your 3 digit number would have `3*7` bits.

Comment: To say what hobbs did in a different way, there are 128x128 = 16384 different pairs of 7 bit numbers, but only 1000 3 (decimal) digit numbers. So you can't encode the pair in the one.